# Safari browser javascript window.resizeTo() support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Does anyone have any idea whether the javascript function window.resizeTo() support is removed from safari browser version 10.11.4. Its working for lower versions of safari browser.

I also tried using the w3schools link and the resize does not happen.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_resizeby_resizeto

Can anyone please confirm this?

Comment: [`resizeTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) was never in the specification so I wouldn't be surprised that it doesn't work in some browsers. Typical W3Schools unreliable information as per usual.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rory

Comment: Looks like this is a MAC OS Issue... the green icon functionality is changed, instead of maximize now its full screen...and full screen the code does not work

Comment: It seems that Safari 10.1 dropped support for resizeTo